# Clicking on a MIME type execute a script to open file

Tags: desktop-environment, mime-types

I want to open jupyter notebooks (.ipynb file) on browser using the command

```
ipython notebook <filename>.ipynb
```

I was thinking if i could tweak my linux such that on double clicking the icon of file the script is executed and opens in browser (by creating some desktop entry or so?).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The exact specifics of this vary based on what particular desktop environment you are using, but it is usually possible to do it without needing a to manually edit the required desktop file by instead using a separate application to edit the MIME type associations.

For the relevant desktop-agnostic documentation, check the FreeDesktop.org [mime-apps specification](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Specifications/mime-apps-spec/).  The particular file you would need to modify is (usually) `~/.config/mimeapps.list`.  If using this method directly, you will have to create and register a desktop file for the script.

If you want an option that's completely desktop agnostic and will even work from the command-line, you could instead use the `binfmt_misc` functionality in the Linux kernel to associate ipython as the interpreter for files with the `.ipynb` extension, though this involves editing system level configuration and is a pain to debug (but if you're still interested, check [here](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/admin-guide/binfmt-misc.rst) for info on how to work with `binfmt_misc`).